# Dependency-free Javascript to access frame content, via IE8 Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, frameset, ie-developer-tools

I need to find a reference to a global variable, K, declared in an HTML page that is displayed inside several layers of frameset.

The most succinct way I can describe what I need is to paste a screenshot and ask that you provide as an answer the code I can use to access my entry point. I intend to paste your correct answer into single or multi-line console mode in IE8's Dev tools.

[image: IE8 Dev Tools screenshot]

Sorry about the questionable quality, it's a screenshot taken from my access to a system via Remote access to a machine hosting a virtual OS, through a virtual gateway.. o_O

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the blue highlighted Node is the frame containing my page, and variable K.

Comment: Is the content different in a modern browser?

Comment: @Jorg The content is fine, I'm trying to identify issues with communication between the host system and our content, using Javascript and a technology called SCORM. I am only able to access the host system via IE8 on WinXP, which is why I must complete this task using only IE8 dev tools.

Comment: Whoa, that markup is ugly (and [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset))…

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did the standard `window.frames.FrameContent.frames.FrameContentBody.frames.FrameContentBodyData.frames.contentFrame.k` approach not work?

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't actually 100% sure how to get into that structure, I've tried things like "window.top.document.getElementById('idFramesetCourse').document.getElementById('idFrameContent')" and adding onto it from there, but I get to certain points and I start getting Object Expected errors (I've had it sanity checked by my colleague).

Comment: A [FrameElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-97790553) doesn't have a `.document` property, but a `.documentElement` property.

Comment: I get to this point, as you've started: "window.frames.FrameContent.frames.idFramesetNav" but the next step by continuing with: "window.frames.FrameContent.frames.idFramesetNav.frames" returns undefined, as there's both a frame and a frameset as childNodes of idFramesetNav. How would I access a .frameset property, or similar, instead of the chained usage of .frames in your example?

Comment: Well, for now I'm setting "window.top.K = K" from within our application, which will have to do. Would like to get to the bottom of this, though!